# Hibernate List is empty when using lazy loading but it has results when eagerly loaded

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I two entities a User and a Place witch are bound with many to many association.
When I try to get all the places for a given user thought the getter method, an emtpy list is returned but the user is bound to the place in the database and if I change the default fetching strategy to eager I can see all the places just fine.
I am using MySQL for the persistance.
The annotations used are:
for the User entity:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name= "USER_PLACE",
joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")},
inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="PLACE_ID")}) 
private List<Place> places = new ArrayList<Place>();
```

and for the Place entity:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "places")
private List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>(0);
```

What can it be the cause of this?

Comment: Are you calling method getPlaces() or just using debugger?

Comment: @paulek I am using method get places an then iterate over the resulted list and try to print the result but the list returns empty. I have enabled the show query and I can see that the query is submitted on the sql server but still no result but if I do it manually using SQL thought the mysql workbench I can see that there is a Place for that user. could it be some kind of dependency that prevents hibernate from fetching the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, it looks like a Mapping issue in Your domain-model. Do the provided entities also map somewhere else? You might run into crazy joins with other tables. Could you provide all relevant entities? Also, the SQL statements generated by Hibernate for User.getPlaces() would be helpful.